# How to make Ionic 2 Slides component with dynamic number of slides move to some slide right after setting the data?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to set the slides of the Ionic 2 Slides component using `*ngFor` dynamically from the data I get using an HTTP request and make it so that a particular slide is set as active.

The problem I am facing is that at the time of setting the property on the component with the data I still can't call the `Slides.slideTo()` because the component is not updated yet and I don't know the proper timing to do that. I also don't see a property such as `activeSlide` on Slides component that I could bind to.

Here's the code describing what I had tried:

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let obj of myObjects">
    <div>{{ obj.title }}</div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

this.http.get('http://example.com', options)
.toPromise()
.then(response => {
    this.myObjects = response.json() as MyObject[];
    this.currentObject = this.myObjects.find(obj => obj.is_selected);

    // Get the index of the slide I want to set as active.
    let index = this.myObjects.indexOf(this.currentObject);

    // Set it as active -- doesn't work here, because this.slides isn't updated yet.
    this.slides.slideTo(index, 0);

    // I tried using ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() and looked at 
    // the length of slides, but it seems that it doesn't run change 
    // detection immediately.
    // 
    // this.ref.detectChanges();
    // console.log(this.slides.length()) // returns 0

    // Calling Slides.update() after the detectChanges() doesn't help.
    // 
    // this.slides.update();
    // console.log(this.slides.length()) // still 0

    // I tried setTimeout(callback, 0) to run this after the stack is empty
    // and presumably the change detection has run, but still no dice.
    // 
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //     console.log(this.slides.length());
    // }, 0); // doesn't work

    // What is interesting, but also a bit disturbing, is that setting
    // the timeout to some other value sometimes returns a value
    // indicating that a change detection has run and sometimes it's 
    // still 0. The longer the timeout, the more probable it runs after 
    // the change detection, but I noticed that up to 20ms I never got 
    // anything else than 0, but at 25ms I tend to get proper values 
    // (but not always). I'm running this on Android device with 
    // Visual Studio Code's default configuration "Run Android on device".
    // 
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //  console.log(this.slides.length());
    // }, 25); // sometimes works
})
```

With Vue framework I used to use `Vue.nextTick()` for that kind of situations, but as `setTimeout(callback, 0)` doesn't seem to work, how should I handle it with Angular 2?

I'm using Ionic 2.2.0 (Angular 2.4.8) with Cordova 6.5.0. Any insights would be very welcome.

**UPDATE**

I've found an Ionic issue that might be relevant: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6703

Answer (score 0):

If you make the call inside of ionViewDidEnter() the slideTo function will work as expected, for example:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.slides.slideTo(this.index,0);
  }
```